# How can I only get the results when you run Python?

Tags: python

```
text= input('str :' )

letters = 0
digit = 0
space = 0

for i in text:
   if i. isalpha():
      letters = letters+1
   elif i. isnumeric():
      digit = digit+1
   elif i.isspace():
      space = space+1
   else:
      pass
   print(letters)
   print(digit)
   print(space)
```

When I run this code all process is appeared. I want to see only three result. How can I do it?

Comment: In general, if you only want to do something once, don't put it inside the loop.

Comment: That should be obvious, but I guess it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of indentation. Just change the code to:

```
text= input('str :' )

letters = 0
digit = 0
space = 0

for i in text:
   if i. isalpha():
      letters = letters+1
   elif i. isnumeric():
      digit = digit+1
   elif i.isspace():
      space = space+1
   else:
      pass
print(letters)
print(digit)
print(space)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of indentation.
in your code,the last three "print" is executed during the for loops.So let them left indented